# set same height for anchor, li and span

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a screen like this:

[image]

How can I put my span and anchor elements to grow in height to be with same height of the li?

I already started with this example http://jsfiddle.net/Gh6mB/1/

My center column should expand in height and width. The left and the right column should expand in height but should keep the width fixed.

Is there anything I can do to simplify this?

Comment: I'm changing the structure to use display:table and div instead of li.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the best structure for this?

Comment: I already setted 100% for then span height property, but the height remains shorter than the li element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the css to match the `<table><tbody><tr><td>` structure, because you had a four level nesting. I had to add a wrapper `div` to the first table between the `li` and the `span`s:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gh6mB/8/

```
#ListaEventosPorMes ul.vermelho {
    display: table;
}

#ListaEventosPorMes ul.vermelho li {
    display: table-row-group;
}

#ListaEventosPorMes ul.vermelho li div,
#ListaEventosPorMes ul.vermelho li a {
    display: table-row;
}

#ListaEventosPorMes ul.vermelho li   span {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 74px;    
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! Why not use <table><tbody><tr><td> in html too? Is html table the best solution for this case?

Comment: I didn't wanted a swarm of downvote from html nazis for using html tables :) But if you want, you can use. Even StackOverflow uses tables for layout, just look into the source code!

Comment: Do you know how can I split my cell into several cells, to build a screen like the image at top? I've changed this example to html table. http://jsfiddle.net/KMjm6/

Comment: Use the rowspan/colspan attributes: `<td rowspan="2" colspan="2">`. BTW, between `<table>` and `<td>` don't put any non-table elements, like `<div>`, `<a>`, etc., because browsers will move them before/after the table, or elsewhere.

Comment: Don't worry to anwer. As it's another question, I opened other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213638/split-a-cell-table-in-several-rows-without-disformat-table

Comment: Ok. So it's better to work without <table> and <td> because I want my all row be an anchor for my next page.

Comment: I returned my code to use the example you build for me, because I want to use the anchor.

Comment: Do you know what's the better approach to me? Build my page using the html table or build with tableless? The problem I see with html table is the anchor element I need for the rows.

Comment: As I see, you will have an optional left cell with fixed width, permanent right cell also with fixed width, and the center takes the remaining space. I think you can solve this with `table-*` css + create some alternative (even if not so beautiful) css for IE 6-7, if necessary.