# split a cell table in several rows without disformat table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a screen like this:

[image]

How can I split my cell in several rows and a column, without disformat my other table components?

I already started, but when I split my cell, my table disformat. 
http://jsfiddle.net/KMjm6/

Take another example, without the use of html table: http://jsfiddle.net/Gh6mB/8/

Comment: And you've got invalid HTML, an `a` is ***not*** a valid child element of a `tr` (only a `td` is a valid child).

Comment: What exactly seems to be incorrect in the fiddle that you provided?

Comment: what you want is not clear  http://jsfiddle.net/KMjm6/1/

Comment: Hi, what I want is to build the screen printed on top. I want to pick my example and add a place to put the image, and a 3 lines of contend on the right of image. And I want that all the row be an arrow for my detail screen.

Comment: I want to split this cell to puther the other components: <td class="label nome">Caminhada da longevidade 2010</td>

Comment: see this whats missing now http://jsfiddle.net/KMjm6/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If could understand your question

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/KMjm6/4/

Put a table inside the middle cell and create your affect

Comment: Hi! I'm almost there in a tableless solution. Can you help to make the detalhes cell streach on all horinzoltal space available? http://jsfiddle.net/Gh6mB/9/

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Tableless Layout concepts.
Only div elements without tables.

See this web sites

http://www.w3.org/2002/03/csslayout-howto

http://girlswhogeek.com/tutorials/2006/create-a-tableless-css-layout

---

Now I understood

See example http://jsfiddle.net/7SGDW/

Comment: Ok, I have another example, without html table. Now, I have to split my span element in 3 rows.